# Excel: How to not display labels in pie chart that are 0%

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, label

I have some data in excel that I want to graph in a pie chart (see image 1) where the text will be the labels and the numbers will turn into percentages. The problem is, when i go to graph the data, it shows the labels for ALL of the sections, even the ones that are 0% in the pie chart. So this really overtakes my entire chart. I do not want to manually select the data as this is a dynamic spreadsheet and sections that are zero now may not be zero down the line.

Is there a way to tell excel to not at all display the labels for the sections that are 0%??

as you can see in the current graph (second image), there are way more labels than there are sections in the pie chart, and it looks extremely busy.

Thank you!

[image: data to graph]

[image: example pie chart with extra labels]

Answer (score 1):

See the article
[How to suppress 0 values in an Excel chart](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-suppress-0-values-in-an-excel-chart/)
for various solutions that depend on your context.

The easiest is in menu *File > Options*, Advanced tab, section
"Display options for this worksheet", to uncheck the option of
"Show a zero in cells that have zero value".
This will suppress the display of the zeros, but they will still appear
in the Format bar.

Another solution to suppress the zeros except from the category labels
is to:

- Select the data range
- Click in the Home tab the small box at bottom-right of the Number group
- In the Format Cells dialog box, choose Custom and set "Type" to
  `0,0;;;`.

For more details with screenshots see the linked article.

Comment: This doesn't work. It only hides the cell values that are 0. The pie chart still displays the label for this value.

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the Format pane for charts and select the data labels you want to change.  Under Format Data Labels > Number > Format Code > type in `0;;;` and >Add.  This will remove the zero.

I have some Percentage labels causing the same problem, showing a 0% label.  I tweaked the Format Code to `0%;;;` and the zero percentage disappeared.

Note, using `0,0;;;` from the previous post adds a zero to all single digits. To remove this enter `0;;;` into the Format Code.  Can confirm it does work :)

Format Data Labels:
[image: Format Data Labels Screenshot]

Comment: nice one + 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't work for me; instead, I found that you changing the number type achieves this. How to: As an example, I want to make a pie chart that is contingent on data values shown as percentages. Highlight the range of data you're charting (percentages in this case) and go to the Home ribbon > Number (little arrow in bottom right-hand corner of this part of the ribbon) > switch the number "Type" to "Custom" > and type in 0%;;. Voila! That worked for me, producing a chart that even if the data in it changed, the values for which it was 0% didn't not show a label and kept my pie chart looking clean.